# Why doesn't the values get inserted into the array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, foreach

I have a NodeJs app which I'm trying to read the ID3 tags of mp3 files. In this case, the first foreach loop works and I can print the array to the screen. 
The second foreach loop works when you log it to the console from inside the loop but the values don't get pushed to the array. The array just returns empty.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

```
app.get('/readfiles', function(req, res){

var fileName = [];
var tags = [];


const testFolder = './tmp/';

fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
    files.forEach(file => {
        fileName.push(file);
    });

    files.forEach(file => {
        new jsmediatags.Reader('./tmp/'+ file)
        .setTagsToRead(["title", "artist"])
        .read({
            onSuccess: function(tag) {
            tags.push(tag.tags.title);
        },
            onError: function(error) {
            console.log(':(', error.type, error.info);
        }
        });
    });

    res.render('display', {
        file: fileName,
        tags: tags
    });
});
```

});

Comment: They *do* get inserted. It just hasn't happened yet by the time you write the array to the response.

Comment: Are you sure it's `tag.tags.title` or `tag.title`? Also try using `async/await`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The values do get inserted into the array but as Bergi has already mentioned, they are not available to be written the response yet. I'm new to this async/await and don't know how to do it yet. If you could give me an exmaple it would be really helpful.